# Fix git tagging?

Tags: git

I did the following just now:

```
// make change
// git add .
// git commit -m "2.0.0"
// git tag -a v2.0.0 <sha-of-above-commit>
// git push --tags
```

However, I forgot to push the actual commit, and now my tag isn't showing up (presumably because I didn't actually push the commit that I tagged.)

I then re-cloned the repo and ran `git tag`, and saw my tag there.

However, my commit wasn't listed under `git log`. So I remade my change, and ran `git push`. This ran successfully. However, `git push --tags` failed, as it said the tag already existed on the remote.

Any solution to this? I tried to delete the remote v2.0.0 tag, but got a `(hook declined)` error.

Comment: “presumably because I didn't actually push the commit that I tagged” – that shouldn’t matter. You can’t push dangling references. Are you sure the remote tag actually exists?

Comment: How are you trying to delete the tag, and does your server disallow deleting tags in general? (Also, if `git log v2.0.0` shows your commit and it's the commit you want, you can just push that to whichever branch.)

Comment: Tried to delete the tag with `git push --delete origin v2.0.0`. Not sure if my server disallows deleting tags in general, but probably?

Comment: Tag is also a ref. When you push a tag, the commit that it points to and the commit's parents that exist only in the local are all pushed. So after the clone, it's expected to see that commit via `git log v2.0.0`. Merely `git log` is not the right command since it lists the log of currently checked out branch, most probably `master`. If `v2.0.0` and `master` are diverged, you cannot see the tagged commit in `master`'s log.

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR: `git push origin master`

[ElpieKay's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928029/fix-git-tagging#comment65213086_38928029) has the correct answer: your `git push` pushed the commit and the tag, but no *branch* in the other (remote) Git repository contains the commit.  That is, in terms of your own Git commit graph, you have—here I'm going to guess that the branch in question is `master`— this:

```
...--o     <-- origin/master
      \
       o   <-- master, tag:v2.0.0
```

You then sent, to the Git on origin, the commit itself (as required in order to send the tag `v2.0.0`), along with a request for *it* to create a tag named `v2.0.0` pointing to the new commit—which it did, giving *it* the graph:

```
...--o     <-- master
      \
       o   <-- tag:v2.0.0
```

Anyone who now clones the repository from the other Git, including yourself, will see the tag in `git tag` output, but will not see the commit on branch `master`, because it's not *on* branch `master`.  The only link to the new commit is the tag.

The solution is simple: do a `git push` to have your Git ask their (origin's) Git to set *their* branch `master` to point to the new commit.  For instance, if the commit's hash ID is `1234567`, this would do the trick:

```
git push origin 1234567:master
```

even from your new clone.  Or, since the tag `v2.0.0` resolves to the correct commit hash:<sup>1</sup>

```
git push origin v2.0.0^{commit}:master
```

The simplest version of this simple fix, though, is to do the `push` operation from your original development repository, where your `master` branch points to the same commit as your `v2.0.0` tag.  In this case you don't need to specify both halves of the refspec argument:

```
git push origin master
```

(this does, of course, assume that `master` on origin has not grown new commits since this point).

---

<sup>1</sup>I say "resolves to" and then introduce this funky `v2.0.0:^{commit}` syntax.  What's that all about?

Since `v2.0.0` is an *annotated tag* (made with `git tag -a`), the name itself actually points to a *tag object* in the repository.  It's the tag object that points to the commit.  When I drew the commit graph, I drew the *commit* graph, not the commit-and-tag graph. :-)  So I left this little bit out.

When we go to `git push`, though, it's probably wise to make sure we ask their Git to set their branch `master` to point directly to the commit, not to a tag.  Branch names are not allowed to point to tags.  Perhaps the request will work—perhaps Git will know "branch names are not allowed to point to tags" and will do the appropriate magic to convert the tag object to its target commit-ID—but perhaps not.  We can avoid the question entirely by telling *our* Git to turn any tag name into its target commit.

That is what this funky syntax does.  As described in [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), `name:^{type}` tells Git first to resolve the name, then to "peel" that name as needed to find the Git object of the given type.

When you give Git a branch name, the name is guaranteed to resolve to a commit object, because branch names *must* point to commit objects.  Tag names, on the other hand, may point to any Git object at all—commit, tag, tree, or blob.  Normally they point only to tag objects or commit objects, but Git won't stop you from making one that points to a blob or tree.  I've done this for various experimental purposes in my own repositories.  So for a tag, you can use `^{commit}` to force it to resolve to a commit.  If the name points to an annotated tag object, this follows that tag to its commit.  If the name already points to a commit, it does nothing.  If the name somehow points to a tree or blob, it produces an error.

You can also use `:^{tree}` and `:^{blob}` to verify that a name points to a tree or blob object.  Of course if the name is a branch name, it doesn't, but the *`name`* part can include a path as well: for instance, `master:Documentation` names a tree object in branch `master` in a Git repository for Git itself, and if you were writing a script and needed to be *really sure* you were getting the hash ID of a tree, you could write:

```
treehash=$(git rev-parse master:Documentation^{tree}) || die ...
```

in your script.